# SQLAlchemy[async] query without joinedload

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

```py
class Items(Base):
    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Tag.id, ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True)
    ...
    tag = relationship('Tag', back_populates='items')

query = Select(Items)
cursor = await db_session.execute(query)
items = cursor.scalars().all()
print(items[0].tag.id)  # 123
```

Why does it work without `joinedload`? When does the additional query for the second table occur?

Comment: It's probably because this Tag object is already in session cache

Comment: Yes, it was true, before this select was another select for tags, and it put in session cache

Comment: Added that as an answer in case of somebody else faces the same issue and finds this question

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because this Tag object is already in session cache